# Row Function Maths ClearContents

Tags: excel, vba, userform

very new to excel VBA and have been working on an exercise to create a purchase order sheet with a userform.

Have run into a problem when trying to clear rows based on a couple of variables.

I have a button to clear the row that has just been added to the sheet, with the following code:

```
Private Sub RemovePrevious_Click()

'Removes last line of PO

If LineItemTotal > 1 Then

Rows(LineItemTotal + POrowstart - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).ClearContents

End If

End Sub
```

LineItemTotal is a range on the sheet that increases as new lines are added. It is declared publicly with POrowstart at the beginning of the userform:

```
Private LineItemTotal As Integer
Private POrowstart As Integer
```

They are then assigned in a different sub:

```
LineItemTotal = Range("LineItemTotal")
POrowstart = 10
```

The problem is that when using the button to run the removeprevious sub, the maths isn't adding up. For instance, when LineItemTotal is 3, it should delete row 12 (the correct one), but it instead deletes row 11. If you press it again (LineItemTotal is now at 2, so should delete 11) it throws an error 'no cells were found' as if it is deleting 11, but it has already mistakenly cleared this.

I have SpecialCells in the code as there are formulas on the row I would like to keep.

Thanks for any help with this.

Comment: I can give you a small but very powerful advice: Record a MACRO in which you do whatever you need (e.g. clearing selected cells), stop recording, and then copy the generated code into your VBA (you may need to do some adjustments though). This is how I find the way to do many things in VBA.

Comment: The easiest way to debug this will be to use the locals window in the vbexplorer and watch the values for the variables change with each step of your code- press F8 to run a single line.  View> Locals Window to show locals.  Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks both! Really good advice, however still haven't gotten to the root of the problem if you're still able to help? The code works if I declare and set the variables within my sub, but not if I declare in general declarations and set them in a different sub, so seems to be something to do with the variables and scope? And tom preston I can't seem to step into this code with the debugger, it just skips to another sub! Thanks again

Comment: @H.B. are all the subs and declaring done in the `Userform` or are you also using `Modules`?

Comment: @DragonSamu all are done within the same userform. I am declaring as private in general declarations then assigning in a private sub within the userform, I thought that this would work to then use the variables in a different sub (again in the same userform)?

Comment: Just as a check, you have checked that `LineItemTotal` has a value of `3` at the first step?

Comment: if LineItemTotal is an integer why are you assigning it a range? Shouldn't it be `LineItemTotal = Range("LineItemTotal").Count`

Answer (score 0):

Double-check your variables since they are declared at module level they may have a different value from what you are expecting. Generally speaking, it is a good idea to avoid module level variables and declare them at the lowest level VBA offers: ROutine-level. If you need to pass values to another routine, give that routine arguments and pass the values as arguments.

Comment: Thanks JKpieterse, is there a way to pass variables between subs without calling the whole sub? I.e. I just want to set LineItemTotal and POrowstart in the first sub then use those values in the other sub. However, it would not work to call either sub within each other. Thanks again.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code and looking at the values of your variables? (mouse over them)